# Google Analytics doesn't work in iOS

Tags: ios, google-analytics

My configuration in Google Analytics account:

[image]

My code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    GAI *gai = [GAI sharedInstance];
    //gai.optOut = YES;
    gai.trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;  // report uncaught exceptions
    gai.logger.logLevel = kGAILogLevelVerbose;  // remove before app release
    [[GAI sharedInstance] setDispatchInterval:10.0];
    [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-xxxxxx-3"];

    return YES;
}
```

In view controller:

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
      [super viewWillAppear:animated];

  ```
  id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
  [tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:@"Detail Screen"];
  [[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView] build]];
  ```

  }

It did shows in my console:

```
2015-06-24 15:03:36.592 GoogleAnalyticsDemoiOS[9540:264576] VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.12 +[GAITrackerModel initialize] (GAITrackerModel.m:88): idfa class missing, won't collect idfa
2015-06-24 15:03:36.619 GoogleAnalyticsDemoiOS[9540:264576] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.12 -[GAIReachabilityChecker reachabilityFlagsChanged:] (GAIReachabilityChecker.m:159): Reachability flags update: 0X000002
2015-06-24 15:03:36.644 GoogleAnalyticsDemoiOS[9540:264684] VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.12 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher persist:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:517): Saved hit: {
    parameters =     {
        "&_crc" = 0;
        "&_s" = 1;
        "&_u" = ".etnoKo9L";
        "&_v" = "mi3.1.2";
        "&a" = 800078077;
        "&aid" = "com.mycompany.app";
        "&an" = GoogleAnalyticsDemoiOS;
        "&av" = "1.0";
        "&cd" = "Detail Screen";
        "&cid" = "caf03508-eba6-42f8-9600-3832ce042907";
        "&dm" = "x86_64";
        "&ds" = app;
        "&sr" = 750x1334;
        "&t" = screenview;
        "&tid" = "UA-xxxxxxxx-3";
        "&ul" = en;
        "&v" = 1;
        "&z" = 663648936779959001;
        gaiVersion = "3.12";
    };
    timestamp = "2015-06-24 07:03:36 +0000";
}
2015-06-24 15:03:36.644 GoogleAnalyticsDemoiOS[9540:264684] VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.12 __70-[GAIBatchingDispatcher checkIAdCampaignAttributionWithHitParameters:]_block_invoke (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:749): iAd campaign tracking disabled because the iAd framework is not linked. See http://goo.gl/426NGa for instructions.
2015-06-24 15:03:46.642 GoogleAnalyticsDemoiOS[9540:264684] VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.12 -[GAIRequestBuilder requestGetUrl:payload:] (GAIRequestBuilder.m:195): building URLRequest for https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect
2015-06-24 15:03:46.643 GoogleAnalyticsDemoiOS[9540:264684] VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.12 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher dispatchWithCompletionHandler:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:632): Sending hit(s) GET: https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect?av=1.0&cid=caf03508-eba6-42f8-9600-3832ce042907&tid=UA-64362429-3&a=800078077&dm=x86_64&cd=Detail+Screen&t=screenview&aid=com.wow.touch&ul=en&_u=.etnoKo9L&ds=app&sr=750x1334&v=1&_s=1&_crc=0&an=GoogleAnalyticsDemoiOS&_v=mi3.1.2&ht=1435129416641&qt=10001&z=663648936779959001
2015-06-24 15:03:46.710 GoogleAnalyticsDemoiOS[9540:264576] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.12 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:response:data:error:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:226): Hit(s) dispatched: HTTP status -1
2015-06-24 15:03:46.710 GoogleAnalyticsDemoiOS[9540:264684] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.12 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher deleteHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:529): hit(s) Successfully deleted
2015-06-24 15:03:46.711 GoogleAnalyticsDemoiOS[9540:264684] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.12 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:237): 1 hit(s) sent
```

But in Realtime view, I always got 0 active users. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: how long ago did you create the account? takes 48 - 72 hours for it to start recording data

Comment: I have the same problem, Did it work after 48 hours like @DaImTo said?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**--- UPDATED ---**

Here is how I fixed :

1 - add this properties and #define directive (if you don't have in your application) in AppDelegate :

```
#define IS_IOS7_AND_UP                      ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 7.0)

@interface AppDelegate ()

// Used for sending Google Analytics traffic in the background.
@property (nonatomic, assign)   BOOL okToWait;
@property (nonatomic, copy)     void (^dispatchHandler)(GAIDispatchResult result);

@end
```

2- in viewDidLoad I use dispatchInterval as 20 and Initialize the tracker shared instance :

```
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;
//[[[GAI sharedInstance] logger] setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];
// Initialize tracker.
[[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:MY_GoogleAnalyticsID];
```

3 - add this method for your AppDelegate :

```
// This method sends hits in the background until either we're told to stop background processing,
// we run into an error, or we run out of hits.  We use this to send any pending Google Analytics
// data since the app won't get a chance once it's in the background.
- (void)sendHitsInBackground {
    self.okToWait = YES;
    __weak AppDelegate *weakSelf = self;
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTaskId =
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        weakSelf.okToWait = NO;
    }];

    if (backgroundTaskId == UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
        return;
    }

    self.dispatchHandler = ^(GAIDispatchResult result) {
        // If the last dispatch succeeded, and we're still OK to stay in the background then kick off
        // again.
        if (result == kGAIDispatchGood && weakSelf.okToWait ) {
            [[GAI sharedInstance] dispatchWithCompletionHandler:weakSelf.dispatchHandler];
        } else {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:backgroundTaskId];
        }
    };
    [[GAI sharedInstance] dispatchWithCompletionHandler:self.dispatchHandler];
}
```

4- in the end of applicationDidEnterBackground call sendHitsInBackground method :

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    //
    // . . .
    //
    if (IS_IOS7_AND_UP)
        [self sendHitsInBackground];
}
```

5 - Add performFetchWithCompletionHandler method and call sendHitsInBackground :

```
// In case the app was sent into the background when there was no network connection, we will use
// the background data fetching mechanism to send any pending Google Analytics data.  Note that
// this app has turned on background data fetching in the capabilities section of the project.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

    if (IS_IOS7_AND_UP)
        [self sendHitsInBackground];

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

and Google Analytics will start working after this effort. I try this in more than one application. If you have any question, please let me know.

Anyway, I don't trust only 1 analytic tool, need some alternatives. I suggest you use Flurry and/or Crashlytics (Fabric). Flurry acquired by Yahoo, Crashlytics acquired by Twitter. Why Fabric, because it has so many features that you'll fall in love with!

Here you can try them :

**Fabric :** https://fabric.io

**Flurry :** http://www.flurry.com

You can call them in

```
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions ...

  [self yourAnalyticServices];
```

And your code looks like this :

```
- (void)yourAnalyticServices {
    //Flurry Analytics
    [Flurry setAppVersion:kAppVersion];
    [Flurry startSession:kFlurryAnalyticsID];
//    [Flurry setCrashReportingEnabled:NO];
    [Flurry setUserID:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", kUserUUID]];


    //Google Analytics
    // Optional: automatically send uncaught exceptions to Google Analytics.
    //[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
    // Optional: set Google Analytics dispatch interval to e.g. 20 seconds.
    [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;
    // Optional: set Logger to VERBOSE for debug information.
    //[[[GAI sharedInstance] logger] setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];
    // Initialize tracker.
    [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:MY_GoogleAnalyticsID];

    //Crashlytics
    [Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll probably consider it in other application. But my customer ask for Google Analytics in this application.

Comment: I don't think a suggestion to use another tool should be considered a correct answer for this question.

Comment: An answer in swift please ?

Comment: @gyer Do you know how to fix this error? - "iAd campaign tracking disabled because the current date is past the campaign window."

Comment: @Vitaliy do have solution?

GoogleAnalytics 3.20 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher checkIAdCampaignAttributionWithHitParameters:]_block_invoke_2 (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:770): iAd campaign tracking disabled because the current date is past the campaign window.

Answer (score 2):

In the **AppDElegate.m** file :

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "GAI.h"
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

   [GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions  = YES;

   [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 1;

   [[[GAI sharedInstance] logger]setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];

   id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"TrackingId"];

   [GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker = tracker;

   return YES;
}
```

In **ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GAITrackedViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController : GAITrackedViewController


@end
```

In **ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.screenName = @"RED Screen";
}
```

**Try it**. This worked for me just fine. I tried it more than three apps. And All are working for realtime. If your account for **your app is new** then you might have to wait for 24h or more to see the result. Sometimes it take time to display realtime data without any reason.