# Google Analytics Campaign Measurement not working

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-api, iad

Who can help with error? - "iAd campaign tracking disabled because the current date is past the campaign window."

From log:

> VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.14 __70-[GAIBatchingDispatcher
>   checkIAdCampaignAttributionWithHitParameters:]_block_invoke_2
>   (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:768): iAd campaign tracking disabled because
>   the current date is past the campaign window.

GoogleAnalytics 3.14
Xcode 7 + iOS 9, Objective C

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? We have a vendor who is working on an app for us and is experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I can see these messages as well, but analytics seems to collect data as usual. There have been two major update to advertising networkds during the last weeks which may not be included in your version of GoogleAnalytics:

1. Admob has switched to Firebase Analytics and
2. Apple has discontinued its own advertising network iAd.

I think you can ignore this verbose message for now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see this question / answer?
Maybe it help you.
The error seem to be the same:

[Google Analytics doesn't work in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31019942/google-analytics-doesnt-work-in-ios)

Comment: Not the same "iAd campaign tracking disabled because the iAd framework is not linked."